# How do i build a real time app with Meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I build an app like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ZwartyZ/83tLc8md/

```
Look into the jsfiddle.
```

with Meteor JS?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Like this.](http://meteorpad.com/pad/EzTMDveoZwCCyrCaq/Just%20like%20Angular)

Session variables are very easy to use.